# mongodb DBException

Tags: mongodb, sharding

Any clue on this exception?

> [conn1026] DBException in process: could not initialize cursor across
>   all shards because : can't map file memory @
>   set1/192.168.1.1:27018,192.168.1.2:27018,192.168.1.3:27018

this is happening after I lost some mongoD instances and they are up again..

Comment: Is this from the 'mongos' log?   If so, is there an error message in the 'mongod' log from the same time?  I'd be particularly interested in the logs from the three servers mentioned in this error.

Comment: Yes this was from the mongos servers... and it was happening just a few times, and that was the only log..

Comment: So, you should have gotten a permissions error in one of the 'mongod' logs on the host 192.186.1.2.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured what was the problem.
In that set1, the second machine had a file database files were owned by root and not by mongodb user. Dont ask me why this was like that, anyways, I just changed the permissions on those files and everything was back to normal..